# Trying heapsort by Cormen, but getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault, heap, heapsort

I'm learning heap sort by Cormen.
When I'm trying to run heapsort on the array, there's a problem and the program crashes (segmentation fault). I tried to put some `printf`'s in the heapsort function and printing the h->size and h->count values but they seem to changed in some way from 10 to 3 (!!!) without me touching them (try to print them before the loop in heap_sort and after)..
I really don't understand what is the problem. please help me.
using Eclipse on windows7.

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heap.h"

void print_array2(int *a, int n)
{
    int *end = a + n;

    while (a < end)
        printf("%d ", *a++);

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] =
    { 4, 1, 3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8, 7 };

    print_array2(a, 10);

    heapsort(a, 10);

    print_array2(a, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

**heap.c:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heap.h"

void heapify(heap *h, int i)
{
    int largest, left = LEFT(i), right = RIGHT(i);

    if (left < h->count && (*(h->a + left) > *(h->a + i)))
        largest = left;
    else
        largest = i;
    if (right < h->count && (*(h->a + right) > *(h->a + largest)))
        largest = right;

    if (largest != i)
    {
        swap(h->a + i, h->a + largest);
        heapify(h, largest);
    }
}

heap *build_heap(int *a, int size)
{
    heap h = (heap
            )
            { .size = size, .count = size, .a = a };

    heap *ph = &h;
    int i = size / 2;

    while (i >= 0)
        heapify(ph, i--);

    return ph;
}

void heapsort(int *a, int size)
{
    heap *h = build_heap(a, size);
    int i;

    for (i = h->size - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        swap(h->a, h->a + i);
        h->count--;
        heapify(h, 0);
    }
}

void print_heap(heap *h)
{
    int *end = h->a + h->count, *arr = h->a;

    while (arr < end)
        printf("%d ", *arr++);

    printf("\n");
}

void print_array(heap *h)
{
    int *end = h->a + h->size, *arr = h->a;

    while (arr < end)
        printf("%d ", *arr++);

    printf("\n");
}

static void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

**heap.h:**

```
#ifndef HEAP_H_
#define HEAP_H_

typedef struct
{
    int size;   //array size
    int count;  //heap size
    int *a;     //int array
} heap;

#define PARENT(x) ((x + 1) / 2)
#define LEFT(x) (2 * (x) + 1)
#define RIGHT(x) (2 * ( (x) + 1) )

void heapify(heap* h, int i);
heap *build_heap(int *a, int size);
void heapsort(int *a, int size);
void print_heap(heap *h);
void print_array(heap *h);
static void swap(int *a, int *b);

#endif /* HEAP_H_ */
```

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable in `build_heap`, so `heapsort` accesses an object no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mafso is correct.  I changed build_heap to return a copy of the heap instead of a pointer and it worked.  Maybe not the best way but it works.  Here is the code:

**heap.h**

```
#ifndef HEAP_H_
#define HEAP_H_

typedef struct
{
    int size;   //array size
    int count;  //heap size
    int *a;     //int array
} heap;

#define PARENT(x) ((x + 1) / 2)
#define LEFT(x) (2 * (x) + 1)
#define RIGHT(x) (2 * ( (x) + 1) )

void heapify(heap* h, int i);
heap build_heap(int *a, int size);
void heapsort(int *a, int size);
void print_heap(heap *h);
void print_array(heap *h);
static void swap(int *a, int *b);

#endif /* HEAP_H_ */
```

**heap.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heap.h"

void heapify(heap *h, int i)
{
    int largest, left = LEFT(i), right = RIGHT(i);

    if (left < h->count && (*(h->a + left) > *(h->a + i)))
        largest = left;
    else
        largest = i;
    if (right < h->count && (*(h->a + right) > *(h->a + largest)))
        largest = right;

    if (largest != i)
    {
        swap(h->a + i, h->a + largest);
        heapify(h, largest);
    }
}

heap build_heap(int *a, int size)
{
    heap h;// = (heap) { .size = size, .count = size, .a = a };
    h.size = size;
    h.count = size;
    h.a = a;

    heap *ph = &h;
    int i = size / 2;

    while (i >= 0)
        heapify(ph, i--);

    return *ph;
}

void heapsort(int *a, int size)
{
    heap h = build_heap(a, size);
    int i;

    for (i = h.size - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        swap(h.a, h.a + i);
        h.count--;
        heapify(&h, 0);
    }
}

void print_heap(heap *h)
{
    int *end = h->a + h->count, *arr = h->a;

    while (arr < end)
        printf("%d ", *arr++);

    printf("\n");
}

void print_array(heap *h)
{
    int *end = h->a + h->size, *arr = h->a;

    while (arr < end)
        printf("%d ", *arr++);

    printf("\n");
}

static void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

This was my output:

```
4 1 3 2 16 9 10 14 8 7 
1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10 14 16
```

Comment: thank you good sir! love this site, got answer so quickly to a problem that was frustrating me for days.